# How to find the schema of Airflow Backend database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, schema, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using apache airflow (v 1.10.2) on Google Cloud Composer, and I would like to view the schema of the airflow database. Where can I find this information?

Comment: Why do you need this information? Do you want to query the database? If you can request the database, you can generate the schema by reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways I can think of comparing our current design.

- External metadata DB. If you can connect to the DB then you can get the schema.
- From your UI you can go to Data Profiling and run query against the metadata tables(depends on your database types(mysql or postgres etc) and find the information from there and create a schema diagram.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Composer [architecture](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview#architecture) design [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview#cloud-sql) is the main place where all the Airflow metadata is stored. However, in order to grant authorization access from client application over the GKE cluster to the database we use [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) service. Particularly in Composer environment we can find `airflow-sqlproxy*` Pod, leveraging connections to Airflow Cloud SQL instance.

Saying this, I believe that it will not make any problem establish connection to the above mentioned Airflow database from any of the GKE cluster workloads(Pods).

For instance, I will perform connection from Airflow worker reaching `airflow-sqlproxy-service.default` Cloud SQL proxy service and further perform DB discovering via `mysql` command-line util:

```
 kubectl -it exec $(kubectl get po -l run=airflow-worker -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}' \
    -n $(kubectl get ns| grep composer*| awk '{print $1}')) -n $(kubectl get ns| grep composer*| awk '{print $1}') \
    -c airflow-worker -- mysql -u root -h airflow-sqlproxy-service.default
```

---

```
 Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
    
    mysql> show databases;
    +----------------------------------------+
    | Database                               |
    +----------------------------------------+
    | information_schema                     |
    | composer-1-8-3-airflow-1-10-3-*        |
    | mysql                                  |
    | performance_schema                     |
    | sys                                    |
    +----------------------------------------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```